# Why adding alloy elements in a steel for increasing tempering temperature while keeping the same hardnes and ductility?

Tags: materials, heat-treatment

What is the advantage of adding alloy elements in a steel in order to increase the tempering temperature while keeping hardness and ductility the same as before?
If I wasn't clear enough, I want to know what difference makes a higher tempering temperature, if hardness and ductility will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperature resistance is especially useful for machine tools eg drills, lathe tools ect etc.

Mechanised cutting generates a lot of heat and equally cutting tools need to be tempered fairly hard for obvious reasons and it is very easy for something like a drill to get well into the normal tempering range of carbon steel, thus losing its original temper.

*High speed steels* for example are widely used for general purpose drill bits etc as they allow higher speeds and/or feed rates to be used while remaining in an acceptable temperature range.